# Flutter RiverPod, FutureProvider isn't working on specific action

Tags: flutter, dart, http, riverpod

I'm currently using Riverpod to manage state in my Flutter application. I have a FutureProvider called localLoginProvider that performs a login API request and returns the response body as a Map<String, dynamic>.

```dart
final localLoginProvider = FutureProvider.autoDispose
    .family<Map<String, dynamic>, Map<String, dynamic>>(
        (ref, Map<String, dynamic> credential) async {
  final APIAdapter apiAdapter = APIAdapter();
  final response =
      await apiAdapter.login(credential['email'], credential['password']);
  return Map<String, dynamic>.from(json.decode(response.body));
});
```

I'm trying to use the .when method to handle the different states of the asynchronous operation, such as data for a successful login and error for a failed login on the action button of the login button on the build function level.

```dart
  void _onLogin() async {
    _presentLoader();
    _clearErrors();
    final credentials = const {'email': '_email', 'password': '_password'};
    final AsyncValue<Map<String, dynamic>> login =
        ref.read(localLoginProvider2(credentials));

    login.when(data: (value) {
      // API request was successful, handle the result (value)
      print('Login successful! Token: $value');
      // Add your logic for a successful login
    }, error: (error, stack) {
      // API request encountered an error, handle the error
      print('Login failed with error: $error');
      // Add your error handling logic
    }, loading: () {
      print('loading');
    });
  }
```

It's always printing **loading** and never went over the data or the error. However the API request is showing the Network tab.

It's worth mentioning that when I watch the provider directly in the build function, it works perfectly. The issue only occurs when I try to use the provider in a specific action click.

Any ideas on how to read from the ref in an action click without always being stuck in the loading state?

Comment: A "family" cannot be a Map, because it does not have valid == and hashCode values.  You end up creating an infinite number of distinct providers.  Either use generated providers for family, or build an immutable object to be a key.